# Windows XP freeze on startup

Tags: windows, freeze

I'm trying to turn on a computer with Windows XP. When it gets to the progress bar before you get to the welcome screen (where it loads), it passes twice then hangs up halfway through.

I'm using Windows XP on a corporate machine, it appears to be recently installed

Comment: Do you know if it is a network login? Possibly the issue could be that it can't find the domain server to sign in on. If it is a network login, check the network cable is attached.

Answer (score 0):

[Use Last Known Good Configuration or Safe Mode](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/chsafe.htm#02) to diagnose the problem.  Hit `F8` just after the BIOS finishes its POST.